# Shell command will not run exe file

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that copies an exe file to various subfolders and then is meant to run the file in that folder. The Shell function call, however, results in no action.

```
destPath = simsPath & subfolderName & "\"
If Len(Dir(destPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir destPath

FileCopy currPath & EXE_FILENAME, destPath & EXE_FILENAME

Shell (destPath & EXE_FILENAME)
```

When I run it in this fashion, the executable does not trigger, and I've checked that the file path is correct.

I tried to do

```
ChDir destPath
Shell (EXE_FILENAME)
```

and this says the the exe file is not found, even though it is certainly within the folder.

Any way I can get the Shell function to trigger?

Comment: You can try                                                                                            Dim myShell 
Set myShell = CreateObject("myScript.Shell")                                  Some code                                                         myScript.Quit

Comment: I am actually trying to eliminate the need for the batch script that I had, so that everything runs from VBA rather than making an extra outside call